# How to enumerate all integers of a given type in Rust?

Tags: rust, integer, range

If I do this:

```
for i in 0..std::u8::MAX {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

then 255 is not included. However, `MAX+1` makes an overflow…

Is there a simple way (without casting to `u16`) of enumerating all `u8` integers?

Comment: To apply the other answer here: you can do `for i in 0..=u8::MAX` (note that as of the latest stable, Rust 1.43, you should be using [the associated constant `u8::MAX`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.u8.html#associatedconstant.MAX) and not [the one in the `std::u8` module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/u8/constant.MAX.html), which has been soft-deprecated).